# Quick fragment switching view binding null

Tags: android, android-fragments, data-binding, android-viewbinding

I have 2 fragments in a tab layout, switching between them quickly causes the views to be returned as null, using ViewBinding. Is this because of the delay to build the FragmentXBinding class?

**Usage Example:**

```
chatadapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(new RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {
            @Override
            public void onItemRangeInserted(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
                binding.chatRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
            }
        });
```

**Error:**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView com.iku.databinding.FragmentChatBinding.chatRecyclerView' on a null object reference
```

Comment: Your `binding`is null .make sure you are initializing view binding inside `onCreateView`

Comment: it is inside `onCreateView` and I get it while switching across fragments really quickly.

Comment: ohhh .. in that case initialize your binding inside `onViewCreated(...)`

Comment: @chandmohd it doesn't work

Comment: @AbhishekAN were you able to resolve this?

Comment: @ThomasBernhard I was not completely! But putting the code related to view binding in `onViewCreated(..)` is better and had to remove few realtime listeners in the app to avoid this NPE. Even detaching the listener in `onStop()`

Answer (score 0):

**FragmentX**

```
 FragmentXBinding binding;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    binding = FragmentChatBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
    init();
    return binding.getRoot();
}

 private void init() {
    // all initialization 
}
```

This helps me to solve my error with null reference